# Keras only giving loss while using evaluate function

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I've trained a keras CNN model. I've later used the evaluate function which is supposed to return test loss and test accuracy but it's only returning the loss. How do I get the accuracy ?

```
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test,verbose=0)
print(score[0])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/models/model/), `Model.evaluate` has the following return description:

> Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.

The loss value is definitely returned, but you must specify any other metrics that you also want returned; in this case, the accuracy.

To do this, also as per the documentation referenced above, you must pass in the metrics you would like in your compilation step in the model. For instance take the following for specifying the accuracy as a metric.

```
model.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

A list of available built-in metrics in Keras can at [this page](https://keras.io/metrics/) in the official Keras documenation.